# Error using checkmouse

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use checkmouse in order to undraw something from my window. When someone clicks the button it should undraw the text and write something else. I'm using checkMouse and getX() and getY() to do this but i keep receiving this error that states:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\project2.py", line 71, in panel
    if (clicknew.getX()>90 and clicknew.getX()<210) and (clicknew.getY()>35 and clicknew.getY() < 0):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getX'
```

this code that i have done so far is as follows:

```
from graphics import *

#creating the game panel window
def panel():
    #grey window, with coordinates flipped, with banners etc
    win = GraphWin("Start Panel", 300,200)
    win.setCoords(0,0,300,200)
    win.setBackground("light grey")
    #drawing the BoilerMazer banner with text
    boilermazer = Rectangle(Point(0,200),Point(300,160))
    boilermazer.setFill("white")
    boilermazer.draw(win)
    #text inside
    banner1 = Text(Point(150,180),"BoilerMazer")
    banner1.setStyle("bold")
    banner1.setSize(20)
    banner1.draw(win)
    #initial game panel is going to have two buttons and a top scores object
    #top score "screen"
    toprec = Rectangle(Point(60,140),Point(240,50))
    toprec.setFill("white")
    toprec.draw(win)
    #text inside toprec
    topscores = Text(Point(150,130),"TOP SCORES")
    topscores.setSize(8)
    topscores.draw(win)
    border = Text(Point(150,120),"======")
    border.draw(win)
    bigmac = Text(Point(150,110),"Big Mac     21")
    bigmac.setSize(8)
    bigmac.draw(win)
    tt = Text(Point(150,90),"T.T     23")
    tt.setSize(8)
    tt.draw(win)
    cshell = Text(Point(150,75),"C-Shell     25")
    cshell.setSize(8)
    cshell.draw(win)
    macmac = Text(Point(150,55),"MacMac     27")
    macmac.setSize(8)
    macmac.draw(win)
    #new player button that will eventually be clicked
    new1 = Point(90,35)
    new2 = Point(210,0)
    newrec = Rectangle(new1,new2)
    newrec.setFill("chartreuse2")
    newrec.draw(win)
    #new player button text
    newplayer = Text(Point(150,18),"NEW PLAYER")
    newplayer.draw(win)
    #reset button
    resetrec = Rectangle(Point(240,35),Point(300,0))
    resetrec.setFill("red")
    resetrec.draw(win)
    #resettext
    reset = Text(Point(270,18),"RESET")
    reset.draw(win)
    #secondary panel window is the game panel after they click new player
    #set up points that we check between for the new player button first
    #setting up the checkmouse
    clicknew = win.checkMouse()
    if (clicknew.getX()>90 and clicknew.getX()<210) and (clicknew.getY()>35 and clicknew.getY() < 0):
        newplayer.undraw()
```

you can find the graphics window here:http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, is there some other method that I'm supposed to be using? Thanks for your help

Comment: Check: `if clicknew:` and then access it - the error tells you _exactly_ whats wrong: your `clicknew` is of `NoneType` meaning it is == None - . `getX()` is not defined on `None`s. Read and head: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/whilestatements.html#graphical-applications), `checkMouse()` returns `None` if no mouse click has been detected priorly. So that seems to be the case.

You could put a loop around the call to `checkMouse` and keep checking `if clicknew is not None` and only in that case go on in your program. But maybe there's a better way...

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
while True:
     clicknew = win.getMouse()
     if clicknew:
         break
     else:
         time.sleep(0.1)  # avoid busy waiting           

# clicknew is set now => use it
```

Comment: i tried to do this:
    clicknew = win.getMouse()
    while not clicknew:
        if clicknew:
            newbutt()
            newplayer.undraw()
but it's still not working. nothing happens

Comment: thanks Jeronimo I was able to figure it out. The problem was the range of my getY() coords..been awake for too long -_-'